# Cygwin Python Script using cygwinreg that can run on the Windows Python

Tags: python, cygwin, winreg

Python newbie here.

I am writing a simple script in Python, using the 2.7.3 distribution from Cygwin. I want to access/modify Windows Registry from this script. I found out that the `_winreg` module is not available on cygwin python but that an alternative [cygwinreg](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/cygwinreg/) exists.

The users of this script do not have cygwin python, they have the windows python install. Is it possible to write a python script that would work on both?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, just do this:

```
try:
    import _winreg
except ImportError:
    import cygwinreg as _winreg
```

Or maybe

```
import sys

if sys.platform == 'win32':
     import _winreg
elif sys.platform == 'cygwin':
     import cygwinreg as _winreg
else:
     # non-windows support
```